# Why is my array buffer empty server-side?

Tags: javascript, java, post, jersey

I have a method in JavaScript to read from a binary file into an ArrayBuffer and send it to a Jersey POST method:

```
function readAndSendBytes() {
    var file = document.getElementById("entityFileField").files[0],
        reader = new FileReader();
    var entityBytes = reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);

    reader.onloadend = function () {
        alert(reader.result);
    }

    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var url = "/api/upload/e2j";
    xhr.open("POST", url, true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/octet-stream");
    xhr.responseType = "json";

    xhr.onload = function (e) {
        var response = xhr.response;
        alert(response);
    }

    xhr.send(reader.result);
}
```

Jersey:

```
@Path("/upload")
public class ParserHandler {
    @POST
    @Path("/e2j")
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public String entityToJsonTwoElectricBoogaloo(byte[] entityPayload) {
        System.out.println(entityPayload.length);
}
```

Whenever I print length to the console, the length is always 0, when it should be 439. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: what does `console.log(reader.result);` print?

Comment: Just the contents of the file that's been loaded. That was just there to check if the file was being loaded properly.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution! Just moved everything but send and initialisations of file and FileReader into the xhr.onload function!

EDIT: Forgot to post my solution.

```
function postEntity() {
    var output = document.getElementById("response");
    var file = document.getElementById("entityFileField").files[0];
    var jsonResponse;

    var r = new FileReader();
    r.onloadend = function(e) {
        var data = r.result;

        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        var url = "/api/upload/entitytojson";
        xhr.open("POST", url, true);
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/octet-stream");
        xhr.responseType = "json";

        xhr.onload = function (e) {
            if (xhr.response != null) {
                jsonResponse = JSON.stringify(xhr.response);
                output.innerHTML = jsonResponse;
            }
            else {
                alert("Invalid Entity File");
            }
        }

        xhr.send(data);
    }

    r.readAsBinaryString(file);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

there is no need to use the filereader, you can just send the blob with xhr

```
function sendFile() {
  var file = document.getElementById("entityFileField").files[0];
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  var url = "/api/upload/e2j";
  xhr.open("POST", url);
  xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/octet-stream");
  xhr.responseType = "json";

  xhr.onload = function (e) {
    var response = xhr.response;
    alert(response);
  }

  xhr.send(file);
}
```